# PHP - open file and uncomment all cols - htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to open a .htaccess file and uncomment all cols in PHP?

I'm using the imap functionalities of PHP and saving the email attachments on the server. Now when a user sends an email containing a .htaccess file for hacking purposes I will uncomment each line in the .htaccess file before it is saved on the server.

```
if ($emails[$i]['attachments'][$n]['name'] == '.htaccess') {
                    /* Uncomment all the lines with # */
                }
```

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Order allow, deny
Deny from all

RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
RemoveType .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
php_flag engine off
```

So a user can't directly access the files but the content is uploaded to a user specific subfolder so it is possible for them to upload a .htaccess which overwrites the defined rules.

I don't let the users download the attachments directly. They see a link that is generated as follows:

```
$msgfile = '../php/downloads/msgAttachmentDownload.php?download=' . urlencode(base64_encode($r16['id']));
$fileLink = '<a target="_blank" href =" ' . $msgfile . '"><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i> ' .$r16['filename']. ' (' . $msgfilesize . ' MB)</a>';
```

In the msgAttachmentDownload.php I grab the url out of the database and download it:

```
$file = '../..' . $r2['fileurl'] . $r2['filename'];
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
```

So the users never see the real path to the file on the server if I'm right.

Would be great to hear your suggestions and I hope this question and the solution will be a good advice to other people.

Comment: Do you *need* to store the attachments under the docroot? It might be better to store them outside and use some kind of resource management script to handle access instead?

Comment: I agree with CD001, this seems better solved by having a file store elsewhere on the disk than putting them directly in the docroot.

Comment: Taking all email attachments and making them directly publicly accessible is a bad idea.  You're exposing yourself to all kinds of security problems.

Comment: Adjusted the question. Sorry for the missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: "Yes, you can easily do that." You should look at the PHP function `fgets`. You could do something like what you want to do by collecting each line, formatting it the way you want, and then writing all of the lines back out to the new file on disk in this manner:

```
<?php
$file = @fopen("/path/to/.htaccess", "r");
if ($file)
{
    while (($line = fgets($file, 4096)) !== false)
    {
        // reformat line and store in an array or something
    }
    if (!feof($file)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($file);
}

// write stored array to a new file or the same file
?>
```

The longer answer to your question is that this seems like a very bad solution to allowing people to access files from your site that they upload/send in attachments. It would be much more secure for you to upload them to a location outside of your document root and have a php file by the name of something like `download-file.php?file_id=12345` or even `download-file.php?file_name=myfile.csv` than to allow people direct access to files that were sent from the customer.

However, there are times when that's not possible or practical so hopefully the first solution helps you get what you are trying to do done.

Comment: Thx a lot. I'll try that. As you can see I adjusted my question and I'm already using your "longer answer" method. :-)

Comment: No problem, let me know if the answer is unclear in any way.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do this is by str_replace or regular expression:

```
$htfile=file_get_contents('.htaccess');
$htfile=str_replace('#','',$htfile);
file_put_contents('.htaccess',$htfile);
```

but **this is not good idea** to modify your htaccess, if you want to decide who can download file or not you can do this in your controller

Comment: Every user should be able to download the attachments of their emails. But unfortunately one can send a .htaccess file via mail and so it will be saved on the server. To prevent functionalities of the .htaccess files I just don't want to say that it isn't possible to retrieve .htaccess files at all, I only want to comment out every line.

Comment: so change the filename? maybe user id before the filename or something similar, or store original filename in db and save it whatever you choose. when you want to send it again to the user just get original fname from db